# Comma separated array with a text_field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some **users** that can have many **posts**, and each of those posts can have many **tags**. I've implemented that using a **has_and_belongs_to_many** relation between the posts and the tags.

When creating a new post, the user can tag it using a comma separated list of values (much like when posting a new question on SO). If any of the tags does not exist already, it should be automatically created. This is the **_fields.html.erb** partial for the post:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

  <h1 class="post"><%= t(:new_post_message) %></h1>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label t(:title) %>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label t(:tag).pluralize %>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label t(:text) %>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit t(:post_verb) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Using **f.text_field :tags** right now results in an input element with **[]** for text.

I don't use tags in **posts_controller.rb** yet, because I'm not sure how I should get and split the string value from the parameters:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    @stream = []
    render 'pages/home'
  end
end
```

Has anyone tackled this problem before? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My preference would be to create an attribute on the post.model to read in the tags. e.g.

**app/models/post.rb**

```
def tag_list
  self.tags.map { |t| t.name }.join(", ")
end

def tag_list=(new_value)
  tag_names = new_value.split(/,\s+/)
  self.tags = tag_names.map { |name| Tag.where('name = ?', name).first or Tag.create(:name => name) }
end
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
```

instead of :tags

The post model will accept the tag list, split into tag names, find the tag if it exists, and create it if it doesn't. No controller logic required.

**EDIT** This code of course relies on your tag model having an attribute called name (if not just substitute whatever attribute you're storing the tags 'name' in), and that it's unique in the database (i.e. you're using something like `validates_uniqueness_of :name` in your tags model)

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked perfectly, I only had to add **:tag_list** to **attr_accessible** in **app/models/post.rb**, like so: `attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_list`

Comment: My pleasure! Good point regarding `attr_accessible`. Just as a final little style point i've noticed whilst re-reading my code it's probably worth adding a scope to tags e.g. `scope :called, lambda { |n| where('tags.name = ?, n) }`, and then using it instead of the where(...) method

Comment: May I suggest this line for the assignment of the new tags instead: `Tag.where('name=?', name.strip).first or Tag.create(:name => name.strip)`

Comment: Huge thumbs up on this really nice solution.