# Using a Hidden Field inside a Rails 5 Partial to Save an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do the seemingly innocuous task of passing an array of tags to a new subscriber form, based on which page it's rendered on.

My `Subscriber` table looks like this in `schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "email"
    t.text "tags", default: [], array: true
    t.text "admin_notes"
    t.boolean "unsubscribe"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

My partial is rendered like this:

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/new_subscriber", locals: { tags: "buyer, LM-house-tour-checklist" } %>
```

Which brings up this `_new_subscriber.html.erb` partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@new_subscriber) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.label :phone %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :tags, value: tags %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions text-center">
    <%= f.submit "Get My Checklist", class: "btn" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have tested using the Chrome code inspector that "buyer, LM-house-tour-checklist" is getting passed into the hidden field value.

However, when I submit, it creates the subscriber with a `:tags` attribute of `["uyer"]`.  This is super weird and unexplainable to me.

Some other info:

- There is nothing in my `subscriber` model.
- `@new_subscriber` is defined in my `ApplicationController` using `before_action :new_subscriber` and `def new_subscriber @new_subscriber = Subscriber.new end`
- I have tried the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345273/comma-separated-array-with-a-text-field-in-rails), but to no avail

Can anyone help me do this in the "Railsiest" way possible?  It dosn't seem like that unusual of an ask, but I can't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it's sent as string.

Try to add `attr_accessor :plain_tags` in model
Instead of tags field use this attribute.

And in `before_create` callback write something like

```rb
before_create :populate_tags

def populate_tags
  return if self.tags_plain.blank?
  self.tags = self.tags_plain.split(",")
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still gives me "uyer".  So bizarre!

Comment: It comes up as `["tags", "{uyer}"]` in my server log, if that helps...?

Comment: Try to set tags in controller, not from form and remove "value" attribute from hidden tag

Comment: Also check in browser what was sent to server. In network tab.

Comment: Some of the forms are on static, controllerless pages, so I'm not sure I can do the first suggestion and I have no idea how to work the network tab of the inspector.  :(